# values in a checkbox won't add

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 23 `checkboxes`. Each of them has a value. When the user checks the checkbox, its value will be added to the grandtotal and will show in a text box. If not checked, it will not be added.  My problem is, it does not add. It only shows the value of the last checked checkbox. How can I add all the values that are checked?

this is the jquery for my checkboxes.

```
function tblcheckboxes(cb){
    var a=0;
    var total = 0;
    if (cb.is(":checked")) {
        a = parseFloat(cb.val(), 10);
        total += a;
    }else{
        total -= a;
    }$('.txt7').val(total.toFixed(2)); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^="tcbx"]').click(function(){
        var cb = $(this);
        tblcheckboxes(cb);
        grandtotal(cb);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you intending to reset `total` to 0 each time `tblcheckboxes` is called, or is that not supposed to be there?

Comment: problem is with your `total` make it global for that function like pass total as params in `tblcheckboxes`

Comment: What is `grandtotal()`?

Comment: i thought that `var total = 0;` is just for initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `total` as the value of the total element

```js
function tblcheckboxes(cb) {
  var total = 0;
  $('input.amount').filter(':checked').each(function() {
    total += (+this.value || 0);
  });
  $('.txt7').val(total.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.amount').click(function() {
    var cb = $(this);
    tblcheckboxes(cb);
    grandtotal(cb);
  });
});

function ChangeColColor() {}

function grandtotal() {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tblPackage">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td width="30%"></td>
      <td width="1%"></td>
      <td width="19%" valign="top">
        <div class="d17_1">
          <div class="d17_2">ECONOMY</div><span class="s11">$49</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="19%" valign="top">
        <div class="d17_1">
          <div class="d17_2">DELUXE</div><span class="s11">$79</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="19%" valign="top">
        <div class="d17_1">
          <div class="d17_2">ULTIMATE</div><span class="s11">$149</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <colgroup>
      <col id="colA" />
      <col id="colB" />
      <col id="colC" />
      <col id="colD" />
      <col id="colE" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: left;">
        <h5>Choose Package</h5>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" checked value="49.00" id="tcbx1" class="css-checkbox amount" data-col="colC" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colC')" />
          <label for="tcbx1" class="css-label"></label>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" value="79.00" id="tcbx2" class="css-checkbox amount" data-col="colD" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colD')" />
          <label for="tcbx2" class="css-label"></label>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" value="149.00" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox amount" data-col="colE" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colE')" />
          <label for="tcbx3" class="css-label"></label>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx" class="css-checkbox amount" />
        <label for="tcbx" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx1" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx1" class="css-label"></label>

      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx2" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx2" class="css-label"></label>

      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx3" class="css-label"></label>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">
        <lbl id="lblBtn" />
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx4" value="19.00" class="css-checkbox amount" />
        <label for="tcbx4" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx1" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx1" class="css-label"></label>

      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx2" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx2" class="css-label"></label>

      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx3" class="css-label"></label>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="30%"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx5" value="49.00" class="css-checkbox amount" />
        <label for="tcbx5" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx1" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx1" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx2" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx2" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx3" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="30%"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx6" value="75.00" class="css-checkbox amount" />
        <label for="tcbx6" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx1" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx1" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx2" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx2" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked name="radiog_dark" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="tcbx3" class="css-label"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Total:
<input type="text" class="txt7" />
```

I have added a class amount to those input fields which has to trigger a total change

Comment: i tried this one and it is almost right. i forgot to mention that i have radio button. part of that "23 checkboxes" are 3 radio buttons. that when one radio button is clicked, it will add to the grand total.

in your code, what happens is, it keeps on adding the radio button.

Comment: @Jennifer can you share a sample of your markup and what is the actual requirement

Comment: those checkboxes are disabled when will they get enabled? also can you explain the functionality you are looking for

Comment: yes it is disabled and some of it has no value. only the first column of checkboxes have values and the radio button. 
its functionality should be, the in the radio buttons, when one is selected, it will show in the textbox and if the user checks on a check box, the value in the radio button and in the checkbox will be added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69098/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-jennifer).